# static content picking css files on when binded to gunicorn

Tags: django, static, gunicorn

this django project ran fine with following:

```
# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

then I ran

```
# python manage.py collectstatic
```

which collected the static data and created it at the root of the project with name static.

then I set the static URL in settings.py file like this

```
# tail -2 eccomerceProject/settings.py 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

and when I bind the project with gunicorn and view it, all it shows is html & css is missing

```
# gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi
```

STUCK HERE !!!

Comment: Please show generated URL to css file from rendered HTML, full or relative to the project root path to this css file. Try to open it manually and tell what error status it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'static')]
```

add you static files in STATICFILES_DIRS

manage.py collectstatic will collect statics in STATIC_ROOT

manage.py runserver serve static files from assets/static folder

use nginx for serve static files is good idea.